# Dynamic Jquery Mobile Pages

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've set up a JqueryMobile application that dynamically creates pages off of some JSON data that my script pulls. All of these pages or inline and pull up fine. However, I need to include some JS in those pages but anything that I write gets ignored after the main page. For instance, I have a simple function that when a link with the id "video" get's clicked it shows an alert message. On my main page this works great but not on any sub pages. How do I make my scripts appear across all pages? Thanks for the help!

Comment: FYI - The pages are all made dynamically, so I can't really use $.mobile.changePage as I don't have a url to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Load the external javascript after you generate a dynamic page

```
<script id="external_script" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
<script>
    function loadscript(scripturi) {
        document.getElementById('external_script').src = scripturi;
    }
</script>
```

Run loadscript(..) in such a way that it will run after you generate/load the dynamic page.

e.g.

```
<div id="dynamic-container"><!-- --></div>

$(#dynamic-container).load("url", function() {
    loadscript(dynamicscriptURL);
});
```

OR

Use a tiny [javascript library](http://ensure.codeplex.com/) that provides a handy function "ensure" which allows you to load Javascript, HTML, CSS on-demand and then execute your code. It can load not just javascript, but html snippet and css on the fly. Best you can wait for them to load and then invoke functions that are loaded dynamically. For example, the following loads javascript, some html snippet, related css and then executes a javascript that is only available when the script is dynamically loaded.

```
ensure( { js: "popup.js", html: "popup.html", css: "popup.css" }, function()
   {
       PopupManager.show();
   });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I tried your first solution to no avail. It still doesn't seem to want to work. Below is how I did the coding, is it right? <script id="external_script" type="text/JavaScript"></script> It works on the main pages but not the subs. I have the code in my head of the doc
<script>
    document.getElementById('external_script').src = 'scripts/inline-scripts.js';
</script>

Comment: Where y ou have the "scripturi" am I putting something like: 'scripts/inline-scripts.js'

Comment: scripturi will be a var which will have the uri of javascript related to the recently generated dynamic page

Comment: <script id="external_script" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
<script>
var scripturi = 'scripts/inline-scripts.js';
    function loadscript(scripturi) {
        document.getElementById('external_script').src = scripturi;
    }
</script>

Comment: You will have to maintain the var scripturi at the level where you generate your dynamic web pages, because that is the point of time and place you will know what script you need to load next.

Answer (score 0):

**script should be included in the subpage's page area or the scripts will not be loaded.**

```
<div data-role="page" id="subpage">

    <div data-role="content"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="video.js"></script>

<div>
```